# postgres server refuses to connect to heroku

Tags: java, postgresql, networking, heroku, gradle

I've set up a remote `postgresql` database for a `gradle` app that I'd like to deploy on Heroku. When running my app on my machine it works fine. However, I had a hard time connecting to the database that I've set up on Heroku, so I thought I'd just try to connect to my remote database. This is the error that showed up in my app log:

```
2016-08-18T13:28:12.606715+00:00 app[web.1]: [JarClassLoader] INFO:  findResource(): unable to locate "org/postgresql/translation/messages_en.properties"
2016-08-18T13:28:12.609362+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-08-18T13:28:12.609487+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.609542+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.609642+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.609715+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:161)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.609970+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2016-08-18T13:28:12.610011+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:239)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.610060+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.610112+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:127)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.610162+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.610440+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.610602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at net.bethydiakabana.mbta.MbtaApplication.run(MbtaApplication.java:79)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611050+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611072+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611122+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611146+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611170+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611286+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
2016-08-18T13:28:12.611331+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 23 more
2016-08-18T13:28:12.688094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-08-18T13:28:12.703273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've read that I needed to change the permissions in the `postgres` configuration files yet I kept getting the same errors. What would be the best way to fix this on a `windows` machine?

**EDIT:**

I've set up a `heroku postgres` database to see if that would help. I'm not sure if it's still having connection issues as well as locating the main class. Would it still be worth connecting to my original database? This is the error that I'm getting now:

```
 Starting process with command `java -Ddw.server.connector.port=37275 -Ddw.database.user=mmcyajlpsbacac -Ddw.database.password=C6nrfQzuoS2ZEMDaTqVEssPDxa -Ddw.database.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-235-254-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5 432/d8hvhhr0h3hr8d?user=mmcyajlpsbacac&password=C6nrfQzuoS2ZEMDaTqVEssPDxa&sslmo de=require  $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/mbta-tweets.jar server config.yaml`
2016-08-18T17:25:22.842387+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-08-18T17:25:22.846667+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-08-18T17:25:23.220849+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class 432.d8hvhhr0h3hr8d?user=mmcyajlpsbacac&password=C6nrfQzuoS2ZEMDaTqVEssPDxa&sslmo
2016-08-18T17:25:23.317758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-08-18T17:25:23.331809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is a snippet of my `yaml` configuration that's read by the configuration class:

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /application
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080

database:
  # the name of your JDBC driver
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

  # the username
  user: someusername

  # the password
  password: somepassword

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?user=username&password=password
```

Here is my `procfile`:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.server.connector.port=$PORT -Ddw.database.user=$JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME -Ddw.database.password=$JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD -Ddw.database.url=$JDBC_DATABASE_URL  $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/mbta-tweets.jar server config.yaml
```

Comment: What version of the postgres driver are you using? What's in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Good question. I just looked into it and I'm using this version: `'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42'`

Answer (score 0):

This message:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused
```

Suggests that you are trying to connect to a database on `localhost` on Heroku, which is certainly not correct. Can you show how you've configured your database connection in the Java code?

Comment: Will do. I've added a snippet of my `yaml` file that's read by the configuration class in my post above.